# Basic AJAX, unable to load content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to load content asynchronously, but my code isn't working and I cant figure it out.

**UPDATED:**

what if i do this?

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="nav-bio" href="#">LINK</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div="content"></div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#nav-bio').click(function() {
        $('#content').load('/content/biography.php #content');
      });
    });
</script>
```

but the content doesnt load.

I started a jsfiddle but couldn't get it to work there either.

http://jsfiddle.net/n8g17x9y/1/

Comment: is there any error in your console

Comment: no errors in browser console

Comment: You are using load in your jsfiddle, that's why it is not worked in jsfiddle. change it to append and it will work. check your response from .php page. is it return perfect ?.

Comment: yep, got it! not 100% on how to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jsfiddle you use load for add static content, that's why it is not worked.

check this http://jsfiddle.net/patelbharat001/zojqwwu4/1/ for your code.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
  $('a').click(function ()
  {
     $('#result').append('<p>hi</p>'); // for data append
     $('#result1').html('<p>test</p>'); // for data override

  });
});
```

but i think that, you have issue in ajax call , so for that refer this url  [w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load2](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load2) may your path for *.php is not generated proper. or try ajax call : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code should be:

```
    <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">LINK</a>
    </li>
    </ul>

<div id="content"></div> <!-- id was missing -->
```

JS Code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('a').click(function(e)
  {
     e.preventDefault(); // To stop default anchor click execution
     $('#content').load('/content/biography.php #content');
   });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I must've typed it wrong in here, my live code is correct.

Comment: Can you share live demo?